# Prove the left hand side of the following inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\frac{2ab}{a+b} \le \sqrt{a \cdot b} \le \frac{a+b}{2}$ where $a,b > 0$

The right hand side $\sqrt{a \cdot b} \le \frac{a+b}{2}$ is the AM-GM inequality, it's clear how to solve it. Does the left hand side also a trivial/elementary proof?

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: The leftmost expression is the same as $$2\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)^{-1},$$ and is the *harmonic mean* of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thats not the AM-GM inequality. Look again carefully

Comment: The AM/GM inequality concerns $\sqrt{ab}$, not $\sqrt{a+b}$. As written both inequalities are false: take $a=b=1$ for the right-hand inequality, or $a=b=3$ for the left-hand inequality.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistyping error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Graphically:**

All means are homogeneous in $a,b$ and you can divide by $b$. Then with $x:=\dfrac ba$,

$$\frac{2x}{x+1}\le\sqrt x\le\frac{x+1}2.$$

[image]

Comment: Note to OP: This is not a proof, without a demonstration that the inequality is true. (To avoid misunderstanding: I'm only commenting as the OP has accepted this answer, I do think this visual approach has value despite not being a complete proof.)

Comment: @YiFan: of course you are right. Anyway a graph is close to a proof, by implicit monotonicity arguments: the curves are smooth, diverge and will not start intertwining. I guess that this could be somehow formalized. (I mean a theory of "what a graph of smooth curves can prove".)

Answer (score 3):

It's also AM-GM in disguise.
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}}{2} \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{ab}} \implies \frac{b + a}{2ab} \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{ab}} \implies \frac{2ab}{a + b} \leq \sqrt{ab}
$$

Answer (score 2):

As all terms are positive

$\frac {2ab}{a+b} \le \sqrt{ab} \iff$

$\frac {2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b} \le 1 \iff$

$\sqrt{ab} \le \frac {a+b}2$

Kind of cute...

Answer (score 2):

$0 \le (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2=a-2\sqrt{ab}+b$, hence $2\sqrt{ab} \le a+b.$ It follows that $ \frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b} \le 1.$ Thus $\frac{2ab}{a+b} \le \sqrt{ab}.$

Answer (score 2):

**Two in one:**

For positivel reals $a,b$,$$\frac{2ab}{a+b}\le\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}2\\\iff \\\frac{4a^2b^2}{(a+b)^2}\le ab\le\frac{(a+b)^2}4\\\iff\\-ab\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2\le0\le\frac{(a-b)^2}4$$ which certainly true. On both sides, equality occurs when $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b >0$
AM-GM: $\sqrt{ab} \le \frac{a+b}{2},$
HM-GM: $\sqrt{ab} \ge \frac{2ab}{a+b}.$
The later can be proved by simplifying it to $$1 \ge\frac{ 2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b}\implies
\frac{a+b}{2} \ge 2\sqrt{ab},$$ which is nothing but AM-GM again.